# Execute shell commands using popen in c++

Tags: visual-c++, shell, command-prompt

I need to be able to execute some shell commands such as moving to the right directory where I have some files I need to decode and then decoding them using another command. I read some stuff about using popen but I didnt really understand how to use it for executing multiple commands.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

```
FILE *pf;
char command[150];
char data[512];

// Execute a process listing
sprintf(command, "cd");
pf = _popen(command,"r"); 

sprintf(command, "cd Test_copy");
pf = _popen(command,"r");   */

sprintf(command, "java -jar Tool.jar -b x.fit x.csv"); 
pf = _popen(command,"r"); 

if(!pf){
  fprintf(stderr, "Could not open pipe for output.\n");
  return;
}

// Grab data from process execution
fgets(data, 512 , pf);

// Print grabbed data to the screen.
fprintf(stdout, "-%s-\n",data); 

if (_pclose(pf) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr," Error: Failed to close command stream \n");
```

Comment: A brief example of what you are doing would be helpful. For more than 1 command, simply call popen as many times as you need. You may find http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/ useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to play with files (open with default application etc.). Use [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) to run shell commands.

Comment: I tried using this -> res = ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", L"java -jar Tool.jar -b test.fit test.csv", L"C:\\Test_Copy2", SW_SHOWNORMAL);   It opens the command prompt but doesnt execute the command!

Comment: @Yousra: Did you try it with `system`?

Comment: I tried to, but I dont think I did it right because it just opened another command prompt! Can you please show me how you'd do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, don't. That would be like using a sledgehammer to knock on a door. Furthermore, it is "evil": http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/